# ggplot2: Why is it displaying the wrong values when set to log10 axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using stat_summary to display the mean and, based off my calculations, "type1, G-" should have a mean of ~10^7.3. And that's the value I get from plotting it without a log10 axis. But when I add in the log10 axis, suddenly "type1, G-" shows a value of 10^6.5.

What's going on?

```
#Data
Type = rep(c("type1", "type2"), each = 6)
Gen = rep(rep(c("G-", "G+"), each = 3), 2)
A = c(4.98E+05, 5.09E+05, 1.03E+05, 3.08E+05, 5.07E+03, 4.22E+04, 6.52E+05,     2.51E+04, 8.66E+05, 8.10E+04, 6.50E+06, 1.64E+06)
B = c(6.76E+07, 3.25E+07, 1.11E+07, 2.34E+06, 4.10E+04, 1.20E+06, 7.50E+07, 1.65E+05, 9.52E+06, 5.92E+06, 3.11E+08, 1.93E+08)
df = melt(data.frame(Type, Gen, A, B))

#Correct, non-log10 version ("type1 G-" has a value over 1e+07)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x =Type,y = value)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean",geom="bar",position="dodge",aes(fill=Gen))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("type1"))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(10^7,10^7.5))


#Incorrect, log10 version ("type1 G-" has a value under 1e+07)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x =Type,y = value)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean",geom="bar",position="dodge",aes(fill=Gen))+
  scale_y_log10()
```

Comment: It takes the mean after log transformation? Correct and incorrect are subjective here, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You want `coord_trans`. As its documentation says:

> ```
> # The difference between transforming the scales and
> # transforming the coordinate system is that scale
> # transformation occurs BEFORE statistics, and coordinate
> # transformation afterwards.
> ```

However, you cannot make a barplot with this, since bars start at 0 and log10(0) is not defined. But barplots are usually not a good visualization anyway.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x =Type,y = value)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean",geom="point",position="identity",aes(color=Gen))+
  coord_trans(y = "log10", limy = c(1e5, 1e8)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 10^(5:8))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Obviously you should plot some kind of uncertainty information. I'd recommend a boxplot.

Comment: How is a bar chart not just a point chart with a vertical line below for it improved visibility... If that point chart is "good" visualization, I'll take bad visualization.